# My slick filter doesn't work in mobile view and also when screen is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm building a property website [HERE](http://savoyrealestate.id/) that has a section for selecting property by project. I use slick to property list and also the filters as shown in the image below.

[image]

If the first time I try to click the filter based on the project it's still normal. But when the screen is resized and in mobile view, this filter doesn't work.

Can anyone here help me deal with this bug?

this is my slick and filter js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider__filter--item').on('click', function(){
            let filterMenu = $(this).data('filter');

            console.log(filterMenu);
            console.log('.slider__filter--item[data-filter="' + filterMenu + '"]')
            console.log('.slider-product#' + filterMenu)

            $('.slider__filter--item').removeClass('active');
            $('.slider-product').removeClass('active');

            $('.slider__filter--item[data-filter="' + filterMenu + '"]').addClass('active');
            $('.slider-product#' + filterMenu).addClass('active')
        });

        $('.slider__filter').slick({
            autoplay:false,
            dots: false,
            arrows:false,
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            responsive: [
                {
                breakpoint: 1200,
                settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 4,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
                {
                breakpoint: 991,
                settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
                {
                breakpoint: 575,
                settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
            ]
        });

        $('.slider-product').slick({
            autoplay:false,
            dots: false,
            arrows:true,
            prevArrow: '<button class="slick-prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>',
            nextArrow: '<button class="slick-next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>',
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            responsive: [
                {
                breakpoint: 575,
                settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
                {
                breakpoint: 991,
                settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
@if (sizeof($data['PROPERTY']) > 0)
    <section class="sections property-recommendation" id="section-property">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="font-size-40 section__title section__title--white">
                        {{ $data['LANDINGPAGE_PRODUCT_TITLE'] ?? 'title goes here' }}
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="tabs-filter">
                        <div class="mb-3 slider__filter">
                           @isset ($data['PROPERTY']['HOT'])
                            <div class="slider__filter--item active" data-filter="type-hot">
                                    <a class="slider__filter--link">Hot</a>
                                </div>
                           @endisset

                           @foreach ($data['PROPERTY']['OTHERS'] as $key => $item)
                                <div class="slider__filter--item" data-filter="type-{{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $key) }}">
                                    <a class="slider__filter--link">{{ $key }}</a>
                                </div>
                           @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @isset ($data['PROPERTY']['HOT'])
                        <div class="slider-product active" id="type-hot">
                            @foreach ($data['PROPERTY']['HOT'] as $item)
                                @include('components.image.property', ['item' => $item])
                            @endforeach
                        
                        </div>
                    @endisset
                    
                    @foreach ($data['PROPERTY']['OTHERS'] as $key => $items)
                        <div class="slider-product" id="type-{{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $key) }}">
                            @foreach ($items as $item)
                                @include('components.image.property', ['item' => $item])
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endif
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs-filter{
    padding: 0 17%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

    @media screen and (max-width:575px){
        padding: 0 10%;
    }

    .slider__filter{
        &--item{
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 10px 0;

            &.active{
                background-color: $orange;
                border-radius: 14px;

                .slider__filter--link{
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        }
        
        &--link{
            text-decoration: none;
            outline: none;
            color: #fff;
            opacity: .5;
        }
    }
}

.slider-product{
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: unset;

    &.active{
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: It may help to include your relevant HTML and CSS to provide a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue.

Comment: i've edited my post above